# Technology in Baseball

Tags: rules, baseball, officiating, mlb, technology

Since the early 2000's digital cameras have been installed by MLB in stadiums to enhance broadcasting/media as well as to **review the performance** of home plate umpires during baseball games.

According to the Umpires Association, are technologies such as **Pitch F/X**, **QuesTech**, and **K-Zone** improving the quality of umpiring behind the plate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that this would be public. The Umpire's Association is typically quiet about this kind of thing. They don't want to throw their members under the bus.

If they came out this year and said "2012 is better than 2011" but then don't say anything in 2013, it's safe to assume that there was a decline, but the Umpire's Association doesn't want to hurt their members publicly.

Umpire discipline and performance review has always been pretty tight-lipped. AFAIK, this is no different.

Comment: Welcome to Sports.SE. I am beginning to find that your answer may indeed be the case. However, I am still hopeful that at the very least some information has either been released or leaked. I have found some information pertaining to the QuesTech technology and the 9 (used to be 11) stadiums this was implemented in. I believe the umpires at one point petitioned to have them removed.

Comment: I have also found information on the minor league umpires utilizing Pitch F/X in order to ensure quality training. However, nothing (as you suggested) from MLB umpires.